# Easy pagination in Java EE with jsp

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, pagination

I'm looking open source pagination component, where I could just give list of items to method that would make pagination to my jsp page. I would get items from database by page parameter and pagination method would do the rest. Is there any good componenets for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [displayTag](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/). It can build paginated tables given a list of objects.

Answer (score 1):

And not just that, displayTag also supports the [Valuelist](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/tut_externalSortAndPage.html) pattern if you don't want displayTag to retrieve the full list everytime before doing pagination.